# Passing a system property to an executable

Tags: java, executable, system-properties

Currently, I am trying to pass a system property to an executable in the following format: `./executable -Dvar="value" other parameters`, since this is what I've seen people do for java files. I keep getting an error in the executable saying that `-Dvar="value"` doesn't exist as a parameter. Where am I going wrong? Are system properties exclusive to Java or something?

Answer (score 0):

The `-D` parameter sets a system property. The system properties can be accessed through `System.getProperty("<your parametername>");`

A tutorial is given here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

The `-D` is consumed by the java runtime (`java.exe`) and will be invisible to your application on the commandline.

Comment: Ok, but how do I then add the system property when using an executable that uses java, not a jar?

Comment: same, but instead of -jar, you call the class. You should consider reading the documentation on how to run java applications.